# how do i config intellij idea + jrebel + liferay dxp

Tags: intellij-idea, liferay, liferay-theme, jrebel, liferay-ide

I was checking the liferay V1.1.1 plugin for intellij idea, I could see that you can add liferay servers, you can debug among other things in the Liferay 7.1 version, the problem goes when I want to use jrebel to work with intellij idea for themes and modules , thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking out [this](https://community.liferay.com/blogs/-/blogs/liferay-7-jrebel) blog post written by Andrew Jardine over on the Liferay community blog. He covers how to fully configure JRebel to work with Liferay 7.

One thing to watch out for is that in the article in the **Agent Configuration** section he recommends setting up a javaagent and Xbootclasspath flags. While this works perfectly fine it is a bit easier to use the new recommended agentpath configuration. There is documentation on the JRebel site [here](https://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/standalone/launch-quick-start.html#jrebel-agent-recommended) on which library you need to use with the agentpath switch depending on which OS and Java bit version you are using.

If things aren't quite working after walking through that blog I would recommend using the Submit a Support Ticket workflow in your IDE (Help > JRebel > Submit a Support Ticket). From there I or someone else from the support team can work with you to figure out what is still missing.